# Insert on constraint-less table, caused ora-02449 unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys

Tags: oracle11g, insert, sql-insert

We have an old batch file which does only such statement:

```
Insert into table_a select * from table_b;
```

table a is bulk table with no index and constraint
after few years, with increments in record counts, this batch became slow
but suddenly for few days, we got this error every time we try to run the batch:

```
Ora-00604 error occured at recursive sql level 1 ora-02449 unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys
```

our only option is to make chunks of data, and insert them part by part, which fixes the batch output, but the problem still exists

we are not dropping and table or object here

can you help us find the cause of problem?

I've checked database level triggers but there is no trigger for insert at database level

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] which demonstrates the behaviour you are describing so that we can replicate the issue. (Sorry, your question is effectively, "in the absence of all the things that would usually raise this exception, what would raise this exception?" and our answer is likely to be "there is nothing to raise the exception and and we can't replicate the problem." So, if you can provide an example then we can work at figuring out why it has happened.)

Comment: `Ora-00604 error occured at recursive sql level 1` would suggest that you have something else going on. Probably a trigger inserting something somewhere else (an audit log table?) or maybe a scheduled job that happens to be activating when the insert is going on.... whatever it is you need to find it and we can't really help with that.